# Overfitting Problem, validation success rate way low than training. What can I change?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a reasonably large dataset split into training/validation categories. The goal of the network is to predict whether a specific spot is a "hotspot," basically True or False. I have around ~40 features. However, running my basic neural network, I found that the success rate on the training data is easy to get correct (~98% under certain parameters), but the validation rate is very low (around ~62%). As I would get ~50% just guessing, I'm not happy with the success rate.

I set up a basic tensorflow program, as I'm new to the process in general. It's a ProximalAdagradOptimizer linked to a DNNClassifier, with different shapes of the network that I've been trying.

Below's the code for the training itself, excluding feature processing/etc. A lot of it's taken from Google's crash course.

```
def train_nn_classification_model(
    my_optimizer,
    steps,
    batch_size,
    hidden_units,
    training_examples,
    training_targets,
    validation_examples,
    validation_targets):
    """Trains a neural network classification model.

    In addition to training, this function also prints training progress information,
    as well as a plot of the training and validation loss over time.

    Args:
      my_optimizer: An instance of `tf.train.Optimizer`, the optimizer to use.
      steps: A non-zero `int`, the total number of training steps. A training step
        consists of a forward and backward pass using a single batch.
      batch_size: A non-zero `int`, the batch size.
      hidden_units: A `list` of int values, specifying the number of neurons in each layer.
      training_examples: A dataframe containing the features to predict the hotspot value of each instance.
      training_targets: A dataframe containing one column, and the hotspot values to target.
      validation_examples: A `DataFrame` containing one or more columns to use as input features for validation.
      validation_targets: A `DataFrame` containing exactly one column to use as target for validation.

    Returns:
      A tuple `(estimator, training_losses, validation_losses)`:
        estimator: the trained `DNNClassifier` object.
        training_losses: a `list` containing the training loss values taken during training.
        validation_losses: a `list` containing the validation loss values taken during training.
    """

    periods = 10
    steps_per_period = steps / periods

    # Create a DNNClassifier object.
    #my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer, 5.0)
    print("creating DNNClassifier object...")
    dnn_classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=construct_feature_columns(training_examples),
        hidden_units = hidden_units,
        optimizer = my_optimizer
    )

    # Create input functions.
    print("creating input functions...")
    training_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(training_examples,
                                            training_targets["hotspot"],
                                            batch_size=batch_size)
    print("TRAINING TARGETS")
    print(training_targets)
    predict_training_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(training_examples,
                                                    training_targets["hotspot"],
                                                    num_epochs=1,
                                                    shuffle=False)
    predict_validation_input_fn = lambda: input_fn(validation_examples,
                                                      validation_targets["hotspot"],
                                                      num_epochs=1,
                                                      shuffle=False)

    # Train the model, but do so inside a loop so that we can periodically assess
    # loss metrics.
    print("Training model...")
    print("Success Rate (on training data):")

    training_success = []
    validation_success = []

    training_correct = 0
    training_total = 0
    validation_correct = 0
    validation_total = 0

    for period in range (0, periods):
        # Train the model, starting from the prior state.
        dnn_classifier.train(
            input_fn=training_input_fn,
            steps=steps_per_period
        )

        # Take a break and compute predictions.
        training_predictions = dnn_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_training_input_fn)
        training_predictions = [int(item['classes']) for item in list(training_predictions)]

        validation_predictions = dnn_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn)
        validation_predictions = [int(item['classes']) for item in list(validation_predictions)]

        # Compute training and validation success rate
        for i in range(0, len(training_predictions)):
            if training_predictions[i] == training_targets['hotspot'][i]:
                training_correct += 1
            training_total += 1
        training_success_rate = training_correct / training_total

        for i in range(0, len(validation_predictions)):
            if validation_predictions[i] == validation_targets['hotspot'][i]:
                validation_correct += 1
            validation_total += 1
        validation_success_rate = validation_correct / validation_total

        # Occasionally print the current loss.
        print("  period %02d : %0.2f" % (period, training_success_rate))
        # Add the loss metrics from this period to our list.
        training_success.append(training_success_rate)
        validation_success.append(validation_success_rate)

    print("Model training finished.")
    # Output a graph of loss metrics over periods.
    plt.ylabel("RMSE")
    plt.xlabel("Periods")
    plt.title("Root Mean Squared Error vs. Periods")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.plot(training_rmse, label="training")
    plt.plot(validation_rmse, label="validation")
    plt.legend()

    print("Final success rate(on training data):   %0.2f" % training_success_rate)
    print("Final success rate (on validation data): %0.2f" % validation_success_rate)
    print("Model training finished")

    return dnn_classifier, training_success, validation_success

user_learning_rate = 0.007

_ = train_nn_classification_model(
    my_optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=user_learning_rate, l2_regularization_rate=0.03),
    steps=5000,
    batch_size=70,
    hidden_units=[30, 20, 10, 5],
    training_examples=training_examples,
    training_targets=training_targets,
    validation_examples=validation_examples,
    validation_targets=validation_targets)
```

I forced the l2 regularization to be way high, and got this result.

```
  period 00 : 0.84
  period 01 : 0.87
  period 02 : 0.88
  period 03 : 0.89
  period 04 : 0.90
  period 05 : 0.91
  period 06 : 0.91
  period 07 : 0.92
  period 08 : 0.92
  period 09 : 0.93

Final success rate(on training data):   0.93
Final success rate (on validation data): 0.61
Model training finished
```

The model seems to train reasonably well, but the validation rate is depressing. What I'm looking for are basic techniques to attempt to see if I could improve the success rate of the model.

Comment: Please *format* your code blocks appropriately

Comment: Have you tried adding regularization? In the constructor of DNNClassifier, add something like `l1_regularization_strength=0.001`, as specified [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier)

Comment: Yeah, I brought up the l1 strength all the way up to 0.5, but that just brought the training accuracy down. Same with l2.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be *the* answer but your problem may be that your features are not very informative of being "hotspot".

You can do a sanity-check by doing the following:

- Shuffle your labels(i.e use wrong labels) and check the validation accuracy(it must be less than 62%, otherwise your features are not meaningful in terms of being "hotspot")
- Don't immediately think that random guess must be 50-50. Check the frequency distribution of your validation set. Your prediction may still be as good as random guess if the True-False rate in your validation set is something like 62-38.

Hope this helps.